# Javascript arrow function doesn't work as expected, working on an array using Array.map, arrays

Tags: javascript, dictionary, push, arrow-functions

I'm new to js and have this task that confuses the hell out of me.

The task is to *"use Array.map() to create a new array that contains the last digit of all prime numers"*.
I already have an array 'primes' containing the prime numbers.

It actually works fine if I only want to print the last digit for each item of the primes array using console.log:

```
let lastDig = new Array()
lastDig = primes.map((value, index) => console.log(value % 10))
// -> 2,3,5,7,1,3,7,...
```

However, if I try to then add the digit to the array I'm supposed to fill in the task, it just ends up filling it with 1,2,3,4,5,..., 25,
even though the ONLY thing I changed in the code was to replace **console.log(value % 10)** by **lastDig.push(value % 10)**.

```
let lastDig = new Array()
lastDig = primes.map((value, index) => lastDig.push(value % 10))
// -> lastDig contains: 1,2,3,4,5,..., 25
```

How can I make this work and why does it change the values if I barely changed the code?

Comment: I don't think you want the  " lastDig = " in the line, " lastDig = primes.map((value, index) => lastDig.push(value % 10))

Comment: @Aadmaa: That may work, but would leave unintuitive code.  `.map()` returns a new array and it's generally expected that its return value is the intended result of the operation.  Relying on `.push()` in this way instead should probably be done with a normal loop, not with `.map()`.

Comment: @David - true; that method would look better with the array's forEach() method. But your answer below looks best to me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to create the array in two different ways simultaneously.

`.map()` *returns* an array, composed of what each element was projected into as the return value of the map callback function.  So don't try to *push* the value as the operation in the map callback, simply *return* it:

```js
let primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97];
let lastDig = primes.map(value => value % 10);
console.log(lastDig);
```

What's happening in your code is all of those `.push()` operations are essentially rendered moot when you assign the return value of `.map()` to `lastDig`.  And *that* return value is an array of what each `.push()` operation *returned*, which was the new length of the array each time.

Comment: good answer, also if you want to generate a `primes` variable you can create a function that returns first the array and then map it with the @David answer. for the function see here https://stackoverflow.com/q/21966000/17716837